# After resize document, new content have as same size. How save new size in ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have problem with size document. I pass vertical orientation(595.0x842.0) pdf and I change orientation pdf to horizontal(842.0x595.0) but When I return `ByteArrayOutputStream` as ByteArray and I try read this ByteArray I get vertical orientation(595.0x842.0) instead horizontal(842.0x595.0)

To write new content I use PdfWriter and I send `Document` with new size and `ByteArrayOutputStream` as second parametr.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf.getFile());
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
```

I expect the output horizontal(842.0x595.0) instead (595.0x842.0)

I need to this dimension in this code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf.getFile());
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,outputStream);
            PdfContentByte pageContent;
            for (int i = 0; i < n;) {
                pageContent = stamper.getOverContent(++i);
                System.out.println(reader.getPageSize(i));
                ColumnText.showTextAligned(pageContent, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                        new Phrase(String.format("page %s of %s", i, n)), 
                            reader.getPageSize(i).getWidth()- 20, 20, 0);
            }
```

This variable `pdf.getFile()` is a ByteArray(`ByteArrayOutputStream` ) from previous code. 
I expect page number in right down corner(x point 842) but actual is 595.
For better understand I send screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `PdfReader` method `getPageSize` but you should use `getPageSizeWithRotation`, i.e. you should replace

```
System.out.println(reader.getPageSize(i));
ColumnText.showTextAligned(pageContent, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
        new Phrase(String.format("page %s of %s", i, n)), 
            reader.getPageSize(i).getWidth()- 20, 20, 0);
```

by

```
System.out.println(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i));
ColumnText.showTextAligned(pageContent, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
        new Phrase(String.format("page %s of %s", i, n)), 
            reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i).getWidth()- 20, 20, 0);
```

#### The Backgrounds

There are two properties of a page responsible for the final displayed page dimension: **MediaBox** and **Rotate**. (Let's for the moment ignore the crop box and all the other boxes which also exist.)

A landscape A4 page, therefore, can be created in two conceptually different ways, either as a 842x595 media box with 0° (or 180°) rotation or as a 595x842 media box with 90° (or 270°) rotation.

If you instantiate a `Document` with `PageSize.A4.rotate()`, iText uses the latter way. (If you had instantiated it with `new RectangleReadOnly(842,595)`, iText would have used the former way.)

`PdfReader.getPageSize` only inspects the media box. Thus, it returns a rectangle with width 595 for your PDF page with 595x842 media box and 90° rotation.

`PdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation` also inspects the page rotation. Thus, it returns a rectangle with width 842 for your PDF page with 595x842 media box and 90° rotation.